# Unity crashes when when reading a WMA file with Naudio AudioFileReader

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, naudio

I am reading and playing local audio files through Unity C# using NAudio but whenever the file is WMA format Unity crashes.

The code I have works for Wav and Mp3 formats, it is just WMA that doesn't work.

I have tried using the dedicated MediaFoundationReader and WmaFileReader classes and I have also tried different WavePlayers like WaveOut and DirectSound but I am having the same problem with them.

I have tried this on multiple WMA files and my paths to those files are definitely correct.

This is the C# script I have attached to my Unity GameObject:

```
output = new WaveOutEvent();
reader = new AudioFileReader(path); //This is the line that it crashes on
output.PlaybackStopped += PlayBackStopped;
output.Init(reader);
output.Play();
```

[A full example of the code can be found here](https://github.com/DanielKloss/BeatTheIntro)

[A Unity crash dump can be found here](https://pastebin.com/7unekhwV)

Thanks for any help anyone can offer and let me know if you need any more info!

Comment: You just want to load WMA  audio and play it?

Comment: Yes, I just want to play a WMA audio file

Comment: You do know that NAudio works on Windows only? What OS are you targetting?

Answer (score 0):

Unity supports importing the following audio file formats: .aif, .wav, .mp3, and .ogg
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AudioFiles.html

Comment: So NAudio can't play a wma file through Unity? I thought that NAudio included the codecs etc to play wma? Have I misunderstood how NAduio works?

Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Also, the point at which Unity crashes is not when it tries to play a wma file it is when NAudio tries to read a wma file:

    reader = new AudioFileReader(path); //This is the line that it crashes on

Comment: Hi. I am seeing this now Feb 2021 trying to convert a wav file, i just saved (valid, plays etc), to mp3. using (var reader = new MediaFoundationReader(fileName)) crashes Unity 2019.3.0f6. Did you solve it? :)